# fetch data from a table having foreign key in yii1

Tags: php, yii, foreign-keys, show, cdetailview

I have a table name `business` and second table `address`. Business table has attributes, `id,buisness name,image` and address table has attributes`address_id,business_id,street,city,house`.

In my business model i have the relationship like this `'addresses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Address', 'business_id'),`.

The thing which i want is to fetch the data like `street,city,house` from the `address` table and show that in the Cdetail view of `Business`. I just know that it can be done with the relationship, but do not know exactly the answer.
Below is my Cdetail view of `Business`.

```
<?php
/* @var $this BusinessController */
/* @var $model Business */
?>

<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Businesses'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-list','label'=>'List Business', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign','label'=>'Create Business', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit','label'=>'Update Business', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign','label'=>'Delete Business', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks','label'=>'Manage Business', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<?php echo BsHtml::pageHeader('View','Business '.$model->id) ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',array(
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'table table-striped table-condensed table-hover',
    ),
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'business_name',
          'image',
    ),
)); ?>
```

after a lot of googling 
i finally did this

```
<?php
/* @var $this BusinessController */
/* @var $model Business */
?>

<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Businesses'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-list','label'=>'List Business', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign','label'=>'Create Business', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit','label'=>'Update Business', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign','label'=>'Delete Business', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks','label'=>'Manage Business', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<?php echo BsHtml::pageHeader('View','Business '.$model->id) ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',array(
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'table table-striped table-condensed table-hover',
    ),
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'business_name',
            'image',
            array(
            'name' => 'addresses', //name of relation in business model
            'value' => function ($data) {
                // Get all related address using the relation defined in the business model and use CHtml::listData to store data inside the $addresses variable as an array using `id` as key and `child_name` as value
                $addresses = CHtml::listData($data->addresses, 'id','sector');
                // Return names as a comma separated list
                return implode(', ', $addresses);
            },
            'type'=>'raw'
        )


    ),
)); ?>
```

now i am getting city name in cdetailview but how can i get sector,street_number too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the deal, i have two tables, `business` and `address`, address table has `business`_id key as foreign key, and i want to show, a `business` `address` in one of the business's view i made i call it `views/(userbusiness.php)`. 
I copied paste this code from my `views/view.php` to `views/userbusiness.php`.

```
<?php
/* @var $this BusinessController */
/* @var $model Business */
?>

<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Businesses'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-list','label'=>'List Business', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign','label'=>'Create Business', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit','label'=>'Update Business', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign','label'=>'Delete Business', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks','label'=>'Manage Business', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>
```

after that i am getting the data of a business `address` just like that in the `userbusiness.php`.

```
<?php $address= $model->addresses;
foreach ($address as $ad)
 {

     echo $ad->street_number;
     echo $ad->sector; 
      echo $ad->city; 
 }
 ?>
```

now in my `userbusiness.php` view, i can echo street_number etc where ever i want. just like below.

```
<div class="booking-item-details">
<header class="booking-item-header">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<h2 class="lh1em"><?php echo $model->business_name; ?></h2>
<p class="lh1em text-small"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <?php $address= $model->addresses;
foreach ($address as $ad)
 {

     echo $ad->street_number;
     echo $ad->sector; 
      echo $ad->city; 
 }
 ?></p>
<ul class="list list-inline text-small">

<li><a href="http://themonal.com/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Restaurant Website</a>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+92-51-2898044s</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--<div class="col-md-3">
<p class="booking-item-header-price"><small>price from</small>  <span class="text-lg">$350</span>/night</p>
</div>-->
</div>
</header>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="tabbable booking-details-tabbable">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Photos</a>
</li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-1">
<div class="fotorama" data-allowfullscreen="true" data-nav="thumbs">
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/img/<?php echo $model->image; ?>" alt="Image Alternative text" title="hotel PORTO BAY SERRA GOLF living room" />
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="booking-item-meta">
<h2 class="lh1em mt40">Outstanding!</h2>
<h3>97% <small >of guests recommend</small></h3>

<div class="booking-item-rating">
<ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
</ul><span class="booking-item-rating-number"><b >4.7</b> of 5 <small class="text-smaller"> rating</small></span>
<p><a class="text-default" href="#">based on 1535 reviews</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"> <!-- made it to 12 -->
<h4 class="lh1em">Business Rating Details</h4>
<ul class="list booking-item-raiting-list">
<li>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-title">Exellent</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-bar">
<div style="width:91%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-number">1223</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-title">Very Good</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-bar">
<div style="width:6%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-number">61</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-title">Average</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-bar">
<div style="width:5%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-number">40</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-title">Poor</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-bar">
<div style="width:3%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-number">15</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-title">Terrible</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-bar">
<div style="width:1%;"></div>
</div>
<div class="booking-item-raiting-list-number">9</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
<a href="themonal-review.php" class="btn btn-primary">Write a Review</a>
<a href="addphotos.php" class="btn btn-primary">Add Photos</a>
 <a href="product-themonal-view.php" class="btn btn-primary">View Products</a>
  <a href="claim-business.php" class="btn btn-primary">Claim This business</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gap"></div>
<h3>Reviews</h3>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<ul class="booking-item-reviews list">
<li>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="booking-item-review-person">
<a class="booking-item-review-person-avatar round" href="user1profile.php">
<img src="img/salik.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Afro" />
</a>
<p class="booking-item-review-person-name"><a href="user1profile.php">Salik Asad</a>
</p>
<p class="booking-item-review-person-loc">Islamabad</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="booking-item-review-content">

<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
</ul>
<p>Really liked this place. </p>
<p class="booking-item-review-rate">Was this review helpful?
<a class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up box-icon-inline round" href="#"></a><b class="text-color"> 7</b>
</p>
<!-- flag and trash -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">

<!-- <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-10">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o box-icon-inline round"></i></a></li></div> -->
<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
<li><a href="flag-review.php"><i class="fa fa-flag-o box-icon-inline round"></i></a></li></div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="booking-item-review-person">
<a class="booking-item-review-person-avatar round" href="user2profile.php">
<img src="img/waqas.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Bubbles" />
</a>
<p class="booking-item-review-person-name"><a href="user2profile.php">Muhammad Waqas</a>
</p>
<p class="booking-item-review-person-loc">Islamabad</p>


</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="booking-item-review-content">

<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
</ul>
<p>Five out of five !!!!!! </p>
<p class="booking-item-review-rate">Was this review helpful?
<a class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up box-icon-inline round" href="#"></a><b class="text-color"> 7</b>
</p>
<!-- flag and trash -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">

<!-- <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-10">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o box-icon-inline round"></i></a></li></div> -->
<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
<li><a href="flag-review.php"><i class="fa fa-flag-o box-icon-inline round"></i></a></li></div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="booking-item-review-person">
<a class="booking-item-review-person-avatar round" href="user3profile.php">
<img src="img/nouman.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Good job" />
</a>
<p class="booking-item-review-person-name"><a href="user3profile.php">Nouman Ali Sethi</a>
</p>
<p class="booking-item-review-person-loc">Islamabad</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">
<div class="booking-item-review-content">

<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
</ul>
<p>Good Experience :) </p>
<p class="booking-item-review-rate">Was this review helpful?
<a class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up box-icon-inline round" href="#"></a><b class="text-color"> 7</b>
</p>
<!-- flag and trash -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">

<!-- <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-10">
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o box-icon-inline round"></i></a></li></div> -->
<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
<li><a href="flag-review.php"><i class="fa fa-flag-o box-icon-inline round"></i></a></li></div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
<div class="row wrap">
<div class="col-md-5">
<p><small>1108 reviews on this hotel. &nbsp;&nbsp;Showing 1 to 7</small>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7">
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">2</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">3</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">4</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">5</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">6</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">7</a>
</li>
<li class="dots">...</li>
<li><a href="#">43</a>
</li>
<li class="next"><a href="#">Next Page</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="gap gap-small"></div>
<div class="box bg-gray">
<h3>Write a Review</h3> <!------------------------------------------- -->
<form>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">


<div class="booking-item-rating">
<ul class="icon-list icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Review Text</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Leave a Review" />
</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<h4>About the Business</h4>
<p class="mb30"> <?php echo $model->business_description; ?></p>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Hours</th>
<th>From</th>
<th>To</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Mon</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tue</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Wed</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Thu</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mon</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Fri</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Sat</td>
<td>9:00am</td>
<td>11:00pm</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
<h4>Facilities Available</h4>
<ul class="booking-item-features booking-item-features-expand mb30 clearfix">
<li><i class="im im-wi-fi"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-title">Wi-Fi Internet</span>
</li>
<li><i class="im im-parking"></i><span class="booking-item-feature-title">Parking</span>
</li>
</ul>
<h4>You may like</h4>
<ul class="booking-list">
<li>
<div class="booking-item booking-item-small">
<a href="nandos.php">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<img src="img/nandos.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Nandos" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<h5 class="booking-item-title">Nandos</h5>
<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--<div class="col-xs-3"><span class="booking-item-price-from">from</span><span class="booking-item-price">$345</span>
</div>-->
</div>
</a>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="booking-item booking-item-small">

<a href="theemperorstable.php">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4">
<img src="img/emperor.jpg" alt="Image Alternative text" title="The Emperor's Table" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">
<h5 class="booking-item-title">The Emperor's Table</h5>
<ul class="icon-group booking-item-rating-stars">
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></i>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<!--<div class="col-xs-3"><span class="booking-item-price-from">from</span><span class="booking-item-price">$345</span>
</div>-->
</div> </a>
</div>
</li>


</ul>

</div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="gap gap-small"></div>
```

Comment: Honestly, i think this approach is not a good one. You really complex your view and it's not scalable.

Comment: I posted another answer and i hope that suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

From your database schema i can see that a business can have many addresses.
If you want to display all of them you can use the following:

```
<?php
/* @var $this BusinessController */
/* @var $model Business */
?>

<?php
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Businesses'=>array('index'),
    $model->id,
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-list','label'=>'List Business', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign','label'=>'Create Business', 'url'=>array('create')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-edit','label'=>'Update Business', 'url'=>array('update', 'id'=>$model->id)),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign','label'=>'Delete Business', 'url'=>'#', 'linkOptions'=>array('submit'=>array('delete','id'=>$model->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete this item?')),
    array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks','label'=>'Manage Business', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<?php echo BsHtml::pageHeader('View','Business '.$model->id) ?>

<?php

//Create the attributes array to use it in CDetailView
$attributes = array(
    'id',
    'business_name',
    'image',
);

//Get all the addresses for the specific business_id
$addresses = Address::model()->findAll(
    array(
    'select'=>'city', 'condition'=>'business_id=:business_id', 
    'params'=>array(':business_id'=>$model->id)));

//Insert all the addresses in your attributes array
$i = 1;
foreach($addresses as $key => $value) {
    $attributes[] = array(
        'name'=>'City '.$i++,
        'value'=>$value->city
    );
}
?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',array(
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'table table-striped table-condensed table-hover',
    ),
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>$attributes,
)); ?>
```

Comment: another shorter way? i am getting this error "Property "Business.business_id" is not defined. "....i am going to edit my question as my business id is just "id" to give a clear explanation i called it "business_id"

Comment: My mentor gave me a hint that, it is possible through relationship, and its a shorter way. Well thanks @Kostas

Comment: Please, share the solution.

Comment: If you have found a different solution please share it because i am really interesting in this.

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer too because my previous one works if you want to have a different row for each address.

This one shows the whole address (city, street, house) in a single row for all addresses using relations as you asked. I have checked it and it works properly.

First, declare a virtual attribute at your `Addresses` model.

```
public $address;
```

Then, in `BusinessController` replace the `actionView` with the following:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $model = Business::model()->with(array(
        'addresses'=>array(
                'select'=>(['alias'=>'CONCAT(city, " ", street, " ", house) AS address'])
            )
        ))->find(array('condition'=>'id=:id', 'params'=>array(':id'=>$id)));


    $this->render('view', array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Finally, in your business/view.php write:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView',array(
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'table table-striped table-condensed table-hover',
    ),
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'id',
        'business_name',
        'image',
        array(
            'name' => 'addresses',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                //Variable $addresses contains all addresses as a comma separated list
                $addresses = CHtml::listData($data->addresses, 'address_id', 'address');
                return implode(', ', $addresses);
            },
            'type'=>'raw'
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```